# How to get status VLC?

Tags: streaming, vlc

i hava an idea, create a streaming server and client with VLC
 - Server streaming file_1 to client
 - Client play file_1, after finished play file_1, client request to Server for file_2, file_3 . . . 
 So . . . how to know client finished playing a file to send next request play file_2, file_3?
Please help me, thanks so much

Comment: I think that if you told us, what platform and what programming language you are using, it may help you get an answer.

Comment: i using java on linux platform

Comment: Looks like here: https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-player would be a good place to start